# AC1300 TP-Link Archer T4U not found in VMWare Kali Linux

Tags: wireless-networking, vmware, kali-linux

I've installed Kali Linux in VMWare and the specified wireless adapter is not recognised in kali. I connected it from VMWare(went to the VM tab, selected Removable Devices, and then 802.11n NIC, and then Connect), I tried NAT and Bridged, nothing. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe VMware supports direct control of wireless cards/adapters.

I believe you can bridge an adapter from the host OS, but this is not going to allow you to use the adapter for Kali penetration testing, as the bridged adapter shows up as a wired one when you go to use it in the guest VM.

Your best bet for using the adapter in Kali is to live boot from a USB to perform pen testing activities. Or dual installation along side windows works well.